# Generic object type with a dynamic key

Tags: typescript

I want to achieve a generic type that will have a parametric key, like that (not valid TS example):

```js
type PaginatedData<TKey, TData> = {
  [TKey]: Array<TData>
  meta?: {
    limit: number
    offset: number
  }
}
```

Ideally the requisites are:

1. should not be allowed to pass `meta` string as `TKey`
2. the key of the array items should be generic I need to pass it from the outside..

I've already tried with:

```js
type PaginatedData<TKey extends string, TData> = {
 [key in TKey]: Array<TData>
} & {meta?: {limit: number, offset: number}}
```

But it breaks the 1. constraint

Comment: This is a good question. I too have asked a similar question, and failed to receive any solid answer. I personally struggle with generics anytime they require more than one _type-parameter_. IDK if its me, as I don't write TS for work so I have nothing to compare my own programs against other than resources I come across online, or if it's sumthin 2 do w/ the TS-Lang itself, like something that those who are writing TS are struggling with. Gonna BM this, and check back.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't explain why your example doesn't work, but a solution would be to make a union of `Record` and an object type:

```js
type PaginatedData<TKey extends string, TData> =
    Record<TKey, TData[]> & {
        meta?: {
            limit: number,
            offset: number,
        }
    };

const page: PaginatedData<"p0" | "p1" | "p2", number> = {
    p0: [0],
    p1: [1],
    p2: [2],
    meta: {
        limit: 100,
        offset: 100,
    }
}
```

[Link to a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgcwJYDs7AgEwCLrgHgBUBpCEKCADwxUwGco7gAnVBAGikN2DgD4oAXgBQUMVABKEAMYB7ZpiKkQnbngDaAXQEAyKAG9R44wFsIvAPwAuA0eP2oAGyQmkwGygCuJgEYRm7HYO4rIAZqF05h7efgFBxgC+QQkA3MLCcihMUGCIEDbwyGgYOHj4AERgAAzlUAA+UJUAjLUNlQBM5Zxevv4CgrbG1TbqVZqBQ00jTeNBYO0j7bOm5nA2hsFOLm42TVVVE8FhEVFQewfJwglAA)

Comment: constraint number 1: meta should not be allowed to be passed as TKey!

so `PaginatedData<'meta', Blogs>` for example, should give a ts-error

Comment: @cl0udw4lk3r I'm pretty sure achieving *strictly* what you're asking is impossible at the moment, although I agree it'd be nice to have. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867 . Of course I might be wrong but at the moment I'd say this is as close as you can get